# How to execute reports which involve a stored procedure calling out to a linked server

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I wrote a stored procedure that calls `openquery` to a linked server to get data from a remote postgresql server and fill a table with that data. This is working fine. The stored procedure needs 3 parameters.

When I try to call the stored procedure from Report Builder 3.0 gives me error

> 7350 (cannot get the column OLE DB provider MSDASQL from linked server "name").

I already verify the allow in-process parameter in MSDASQL.

I can't find a solution for this. If I run the stored procedure from Mgmt Studio, it works fine. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

The report only have to show the file data by row. I can run the stored procedure and the report separately and works but I have to do this manually, my requirement needs a report subscription, so have to be automatic.

Any idea how to solve this or a workaround?

PD: sorry for my english, and thank you in advance.

Comment: So have you debugged it, by trying to execute the Linked Server reference path?  I would start by trying to execute it with your Admin rights, first.  Then work you way from there.  Although in an SSIS package, i would forgo the Linked Server and do a direct connect to the server itself and do what needs to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I had to make separates works, so create a job that run the store procedure, generate the info on a table, and then run report reading the info from the table. This works.
Thank you all.